# Create a bat file for git-bash script

Tags: batch-file, git-bash

Hi all. I gave a git-bash installed and want some automatisation. I've got a .bat file, which I want to run as

```
some.bat param | iconv -cp1251 > l.log | tail -f l.log
```

And I want to run it not in WinCMD but in git-bash shell - tell me plz how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Git bash on windows uses [BASH](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html). You can use bash to create a quick script that can take in parameters and echo them so that you can pipe them to your next utility.

It could look something like this

File: some.sh

```
 #!/bin/bash

 #Lots of fun bash scripting here...

 echo $1 
 # $1 here is the first parameter sent to this script. 
 # $2 is the second... etc. $0 is the script name
```

then by setting some.sh as executable

```
$ chmod +x some.sh
```

You'll then be able to execute it in the git-bash shell

```
./some.sh param | cat ... etc | etc...
```

You can read about bash programming

I'd reccomend looking at some bash scripting tutorials such as [this one](http://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-script.php)